# Asterisk, two IP address, same segment, same phisical interface

Tags: asterisk

I have two IP address on my server on the same physical interface:

```
eth0     10.10.10.11
eth0:0   10.10.10.12

Client IP address: 20.30.40.99
```

The problem is that when a extension (in another subnet) tries register, the server receive the request by the IP 10.10.10.11, but it tries to response by the IP 10.10.10.12 (according to my interpretation of the log), so the extension not register.

It's the log:

```
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: = Looking for  Call ID: ODU1N2VlNDlkYjQ2NzJkNTU1NTI0ZDc4MWFjOGFhY2I. (Checking From) --From tag d979d256 --To-tag   
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] acl.c: For destination '20.30.40.99', our source address is '10.10.10.12'.
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: Setting SIP_TRANSPORT_UDP with address 10.10.10.12:5060
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] netsock2.c: Splitting '20.30.40.99:52607' into...
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] netsock2.c: ...host '20.30.40.99' and port '52607'.
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: Allocating new SIP dialog for ODU1N2VlNDlkYjQ2NzJkNTU1NTI0ZDc4MWFjOGFhY2I. - PUBLISH (No RTP)
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: **** Received PUBLISH (15) - Command in SIP PUBLISH
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: Trying to put 'SIP/2.0 489' onto UDP socket destined for 20.30.40.99:52607
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: SIP message could not be handled, bad request: ODU1N2VlNDlkYjQ2NzJkNTU1NTI0ZDc4MWFjOGFhY2I.                          
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: Destroying SIP dialog ODU1N2VlNDlkYjQ2NzJkNTU1NTI0ZDc4MWFjOGFhY2I.
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: = Looking for  Call ID: Y2M3MmEyMjU2YTkyYzQxODlhNjI5N2Y1Y2NiMjkyMjA. (Checking From) --From tag 1262b86c --To-tag   
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: **** Received REGISTER (2) - Command in SIP REGISTER
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] chan_sip.c: Ignoring SIP message because of retransmit (REGISTER Seqno 2491, ours 2491)
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] netsock2.c: Splitting '20.30.40.99:52607' into...
[Apr  3 08:10:19] DEBUG[1758] netsock2.c: ...host '20.30.40.99' and port '52607'.
```

How can I make that Asterisk respond by the 10.10.10.11 (eth0) IP, and not by 10.10.10.12 (eth0:0)?

Answer (score -1):

Chan sip will select first address availible.

You can do

1) move to PJSIP and use different transport sections

2) start two asterisks, one on other ip, do interconnection.

3) If you need work on one ip only, use bind=, after that use externip= directive.